# Error among class methods, Python Programming

Tags: python

Adding `computerBoard = self.getComputerBoard(self.newBoard)` into my `def computerMove` doesn't work. It only tells me that:

```
computerBoard[x][y] = self.board[x][y]
```

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

It is probably something about my defining computerboard in the `def getComputerBoard` but I don't understand why...

```
class BoardHandler: 
def __init__ (self):
    self.board = None
    self.size = self.askSize()           
    self.newBoard()

def newBoard(self): 
    self.board = [] 
    for i in range(self.size):
        self.board.append([' '] * self.size)
```

Comment: Where is self.board defined?

Comment: Put the whole class in

Comment: Either `self.board[x]` or `computerBoard[x]` is not set to a list/array.

Comment: What is the `newBoard` parameter to `getComputerBoard` for?

Comment: updated @SamCraig

Comment: The `__init__` method never sets `self.board` to a board.

Comment: Maybe it should be `self.board = self.newBoard()`

Comment: I'll go back and check!

Comment: updated! @Barmar

Comment: Well considering board is an empty list it should still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newBoard` doesn't return a new board, it just initializes `self.board`. So

```
computerBoard = self.newBoard()
```

sets `computerBoard` to `None`, as well as wiping out whatever was in `self.board`.

You should change `newBoard` so it returns the board instead of updating `self`.

```
def newBoard(self): 
    board = [] 
    for i in range(self.size):
        board.append([' '] * self.size)
    return board
```

or more simply:

```
def newBoar(self):
    return [[' '] * self.size for i in range(self.size)]
```

Then change the `__init__` method to use it this way:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.size = self.askSize()
    self.board = self.newBoard()
```

Comment: it tells me `   return board
NameError: name 'board' is not defined`

Comment: Huh? It was defined 2 lines earlier in `board = []`